# Git rm --cached and checkout

Tags: git

I've issued the following command

```
git rm --cached .idea
```

on my `develop` branch, 'cause i don't want to track ide config files. Files have been removed from index but they're still on filesystem, which is exactly my original goal.

Now when i try to checkout another branch, git fails because they're still in the index of the other branch - this is expected.

However, i need to remove these files from the index of any branch, so how can i issue the same `git rm --cached` command on a branch i can't checkout to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file on the other branch is the same as the untracked file on the disk, you can `git checkout -f`, and then `git rm --cached`. If not, and you want to save the untracked file without git's knowledge, you must do exactly that: put it away in `~/tmp` or something, clean up git's view, and `mv` it back to the repository directory. Also, put it in `.gitignore` immediately to avoid tracking it by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same situation, I tend do this until all `BRANCH_WHERE_FILE_REMAINS` are gone.

```
git rebase BRANCH_WHERE_FILE_IS_REMOVED BRANCH_WHERE_FILE_REMAINS
```

Note: This doesn't cause checking out of commits where `.idea` remains, because rebase's cherry-picking is based after the commit where the file is already removed.

However, note that if at any point you do `git rebase --abort`, rebase will try going back to a commit where `.idea` was still in the index, and you'll probably face trouble there.  (Backing up of `.idea` is recommended before attempting.)

`BRANCH_WHERE_FILE_IS_REMOVED` can just be the commit-id if there's no such branch.

Comment: Not working. I'm on develop ( the branch with the .idea files) and issued git rebase master (master is the branch without the files), but i get "error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:"

Comment: Are you sure that's not *"I'm on develop (the branch **without** the .idea files) and issued git rebase master (master is the branch **with** the files) ..."*?  Because this is more in line with your original question, as well as the error message you're getting.

Comment: Anyhow, the command you need to issue is backwards.  It's `git rebase develop master`.  ***But*** this rebases `master` on `develop`, and I'm pretty sure you don't want this.  The above answer actually assumed that by *"Now when i try to checkout another branch"*, you meant ***other feature branches***, not your mainline.  Indeed, I see how you'd run into your initial problem if you wanted to checkout your mainline in order to issue `git merge develop`.

Comment: Yep that's the problem - my bad i didn't mention that the involved branch was my master. I'll try your solution if i run into this again