# Is there a way to un-git folder/files in ALL branches at once?

Tags: git

I added a directory that I track to `.gitignore`. Now I know that I have to

```
git rm -r --cached path/to/the/directory/
```

to remove it from index. But it seems that I have to do it in every single branch I have.

Is there a short way to

1. Synchronize `.gitignore` over all branches?
2. Run `git rm -r --cached path/to/the/directory/` (or something like that) for all branches at once?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938289/git-rm-cached-and-checkout

Comment: How are you using branches? With most development workflows, changes to some "develop" branch will eventually be merged into other branches anyway.

Comment: @Thomas Eventually, yes. But I have a branch which will be merged in several months may be so I wanted to clean all branches at once and forget about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a short way to synchronize changes in a file (`.gitignore`) and untrack multiple files over all branches?

No. The reason is that such a change requires a commit. And you cannot just synchronize commits automatically over multiple branches. Instead, you are expected to *explicitly* carry over those changes from another branch. There are multiple ways to do this, including simply [*merging*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) your branches, or [*cherry-picking*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) individual commits.